# Include libraries with Composer, NPM or Bower

Tags: php, npm, composer-php, gulp, bower

I have been getting into Composer, NPM and Bower recently. I no there's a lot of overlap between their capabilities and I was wondering if my approach is sane? If not, what should I do?

I typically start my PHP projects by setting up composer to load my PHP libraries and dependencies. After that I use NPM to install Gulp and all the gulp plugins I use. And finally I use Bower to get the JS and CSS libraries.

Most of these can load from GitHub, so theoretically I could use Composer to install my JS/CSS or Bower to load my PHP. I'm pretty much set on Composer for it's autoloading capabilities, so I suppose my question is whether I should dump Bower?

Currently when I deploy, I checkout my repo and call `npm install` which installs Gulp etc. In my `package.json` I use `"scripts": {"install": "gulp install"}` which kicks off my `install` task in my `gulpfile.js`. That loads in the `gulp-composer` and `gulp-bower` plugins that kick off the Composer and Bower installs.

Comment: You can replace npm/bower by [composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin).

Comment: @TomášVotruba interesting option. I tried it on a test project, but I couldn't get Gulp to install properly. I do use Gulp to automate the install of Composer and Bower dependancies, but I also use it for lots of other stuff like image processing as well, so Gulp is a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all do pretty much the same, the difference is their default package list (NPM purely NodeJS, Composer mostly PHP, Bower purely js/css, etc.) and the language they're written in.

However, they all have one limitation: They can install packages in just one location. This means that you can't install `some/php-framework` in `vendor/` and `my-css-framework` in `web/`.

The location is very important: You often want your PHP code/NodeJS libs to live outside the public root, but your assets should be inside your public root.

I think it's a very good practice to, if you are able too, use each dependency manager for the language it was designed for (e.g. Composer also does some PHP specific stuff like autoloading, while NPM does some NodeJS specific stuff).

Comment: You wouldn't want to make `bower_components` public either. That's why we use gulp or another tool to pull the components out of that directory, maybe compress and concat them, and then move them into a public directory. The location is not very important at all. He's already settled on Composer because of the autoloading, but you do raise a good point about NPM -- sometimes `npm install` does more than just download a handful of files, it compiles platform-specific libs. You can't really get away from npm for that AFAIK.